# knife(chef) - is it possible to get the instructions for a recipe in a specific format?

Tags: chef-infra, knife

thanks in advance for the help!

when I use the following knife command:

```
knife cookbook show my_cookbook its_version recipes recipe_name -F json/yaml
```

I just get the raw data, not in a json/yaml format.
I was wondering if there was a way for me to get this data in a specific format without having to write a script to convert everything...

And, if there's no way to do that through command line, do you guys know any python script/library that would help me convert this data in json/yaml?

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The instructions are the Ruby source code of the recipe, that's all there is. Chef does actually run that code as part of the execution, you cannot convert a Chef recipe to static data in the general case.